# Live testing jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, firefox, testing, plugins, live

Is it possible to conveniently test jQuery selectors on some random web page using some sort of plugin for browser (Firefox)?

It would be nice if it could automatically highlight selected elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) + [jQuerify bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet) (if there's no jQuery included on the page).

You can achieve highlighting using outline, `$('.test').css('outline', '3px solid red');`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can simply use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/1843) for **Firefox or Chrome**, or, you can use something like [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/). Firebug being exactly what you need

Hope this helps

Comment: True, I use jsfiddle as well, but I just think Jsbin is simpler. They're both great though

Answer (score 1):

Perfect extension to embed jQuery into Chrome Console as simple as you can imagine. This extension also indocates if jQuery has been already embeded into page.

This extension used to embed jQuery into any page you want. It allows to use jQuery in the console shell (You can invoke Chrome console by "Ctrl+Shift+j").

To embed jQuery into selected tab click on extention button.

*LINK* to extension:
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc